# How can I ignore "\b" and "\e" but not "\n" with echo

Tags: linux, bash, shell, latex

First of all sorry for the beginner question, I am quite new to shell scripting. I am creating a simple script to manage my figures for LaTeX documents. Long story short I want to copy

```latex
\begin{figure}
\centering
\inkfig{$name}
\end{figure}
```

to the clipboard. Thus I thought about using this command

```bsh
echo -e "\begin{figure}\n\centering\n\inkfig{$name}\n\end{figure}" | xclip -selection clipboard
```

but this interprets the `\b` and `\e` as escapes. Conversely if I run `echo` without the `-e` flag the `\n` isn't interpreted. So I need a way to interpret `\n` but not `\b` and `\e`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `printf '%b' instead of `echo`

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? I don't completely understand how the % specifiers work in the bash printf (after reading the manpage)


_edit_ nevermind, I figured it out :) thanks for the response

Comment: [Why is `printf` better than `echo`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/108618)

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer is to use real newlines:

```
echo '\begin{figure}
\centering...' | ...
```

But if you have the string with `\n` in it in a variable you can use bash to replace just these by a real newline:

```
var='\begin{figure}\n\centering...'
newvar="${var//\\n/
}"
echo "$newvar" | ...
```

Look for *Pattern substitution* in the bash man page.